# Force Immediate Purge of Permanent Table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**Is there any way to force Snowflake to immediately purge a dropped, permanent table?**

When a permanent table is dropped the fail-safe feature of Snowflake will ensure it can be "un-
dropped" for 7-days. This incurs storage costs for that 7-days until the data is purged.

I am aware that both temporary and transient tables do not have fail-safe, however the table(s) I need immediately purged on drop are permanent tables.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-temp-transient.html#comparison-of-table-types

If this is not possible, would deleting all records in the table prior to dropping it help at all with storage costs?

Comment: As Mike mentioned - it does not help. Having said that you change the default behavior of creating a transient table instead of a permanent table for future, outlined in the article below:
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Making-Transient-table-by-Default Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The only way to avoid the fail-safe is to leverage temporary or transient tables.  Deleting all of the records, first, doesn't help you.